# mvc 4 Model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.listboxfor

i'm using razor's listboxfor for the first time, but my Model is always null.
after reading similar posts and tryouts it still won't work.

Person.cshtml

```
@model SampleApp.Web.ViewModel.PersonViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}

<article>
   <p>
      Welcome to example page. 
   </p>

   <p>
     <div class="container">

 //Post data works as expected, controllers create method write to db successfully 
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personen</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
           @* @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surrname)
        </div>
</fielset>
 </div>

 <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
 </p>
}

//binding to Model fails, Model is null. Not be able to debug anything in    controller action, it stops when "loading" the page
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetListBoxData", "Person"))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ListboxData, Model.ListboxData);
}

</div>
```

PersonController.cs

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetListBoxData()
    {
        var data = new List<PersonViewModel>();
        data.Add(new PersonViewModel{Name = "Test", Surrname="testsurrname", Age=30});

        var viewModel = new PersonViewModel()
        {
            ListboxData = data.AsEnumerable().Select(s=> new SelectListItem{Value=s.Name ,Text = s.Surrname}),
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetListBoxData(PersonViewModel persondata)
    {
        //TODO: handle values from View
        return View(this);
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, Surrname, Age")]  PersonViewModel persondata)
    {
        try
        {
            PersonService personDataProvider = new PersonService();
            personDataProvider.SavePerson(persondata);

            return new RedirectResult("SomewhereToGo");
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            //TODO: Log
        }

        return View(this);
    }
```

PersonViewModel

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surrname { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListboxData { get; set; }
}
```

writing values from editFor to db works as expected without code for listboxfor. 
after adding it to my html it should be filled from db on page loading, but I get a ReferenceNotSet Exception on page loading. Model.ListboxData is null, before GetListBoxData action is called.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why is there a "<p>" in your view file after the model declaration?

Comment: oh sorry, there is some html code before, copy&pasted from cshtml

Comment: Person.cshtml?  Your controller is Index.... do you have a Person action?  because by default it will route through that.  Normally you'd have index.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

1. Your form should submit the data via POST, not GET. And, you don't need to use `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`, unless you want to upload files through your from.
2. You need two Index Actions in your Controller, one is for sending the data from your Controller to the View, and the other one is for getting the data back from the View, when the form is submitted (POST) to the server.
3. The first argument you pass to your ListBox (the expression) refers to the Property in your Model that the selected item from your ListBox will be stored in, which in this case is PersonId.

So, your View should look like this:

```
@model MVCApplication.Web.ViewModel.PersonViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Person"))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PersonId, Model.ListBoxData)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Then, in your Controller, you'll have two Actions like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new PersonViewModel()
    {
        ListboxData = data.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.PersonId.ToString(), Text = s.PersonId.ToString() }).AsEnumerable();
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PersonViewModel viewModel)
{
  // code to save the data in the database or whatever you want to do with the data coming from the View
}
```

By the way, in your ViewModel, you don't have to define your ListBoxData property like that, just do this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListBoxData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarification but problem still exists (Model is null). I've a few EditorFor Elements in my Html which are wired with a create method in controller -> database.this works fine. Debugging in Controllers Index methods doesn't work, it crashes before when initializing the page, model is null.Does it has to be set explicitly somewhere for null check? thanks for your time

Comment: What do you mean it crashes?

Comment: it stops in my cshtml with a reference not set exception (because Model is null)

Comment: Are your Actions exactly like the ones in my answer?  Do you get the correct data from the database in your Action?

Comment: The Model being null doesn't have anything to do with the ListBox.

Comment: they are nearly the same, I've updated my question and html with full code and comments. yes model bindin has nothing to do with listboxfor, but that's the only time I would like to use Model property (currently).

Comment: Why do you have two forms in your View? How come this is even nearly close to my answer?

Comment: sorry there's a curly brace at the end of first form. Why shouldn't work it with two forms?

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't make sense. There's no submit button in the second form, so how do you expect the form to be posted to your Controller. It's not clear what you want to do with your second form.  Please update your question, and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I need to know is what you want to do with your ListBox? What do you expect to happen when you select an option from the ListBox? You shouldn't have two forms like that in your View.

Comment: Also, post your PersonViewModel completely. You've just posted a porting of it.

Comment: there're only two properties in my viewmodel, as much as I currently need for my html

Comment: So, what's this: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)`? It seems like you don't have any idea what you are doing.

Comment: again, problem is in ListBoxFor that Model.ListboxData -> MODEL is null! it has nothing to to with first form (where i'm using some editorFor fields). when i comment out all except of second form (where i'm using listboxfor), it's still not working.